# Cube normals on voxel engine producing odd results

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, voxel, shadows

I am trying to add normals to my voxel engines 16x16 cube chunks.  When I render everything I get odd results.  I am not sure if I have placed my normals incorrectly or if implementing simple shadows with lighting wont work how I am using it.

The following is the vertexes for each of my cubes and there respective normals.

```
public void putVertices(float tx, float ty, float tz, FloatBuffer vertexPositionData) {
    float l_length = Constants.BLOCK_SIZE;
    float l_height = Constants.BLOCK_SIZE;
    float l_width = Constants.BLOCK_SIZE;
    vertexPositionData.put(new float[]{
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,

            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,

            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty,zOffset +  -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty,zOffset +  -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,

            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty,zOffset +  l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,

            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, -l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, -l_height + ty,zOffset +  l_width + tz,

            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty,zOffset +  -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + -l_width + tz,
            xOffset + -l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz,
            xOffset + l_length + tx, l_height + ty, zOffset + l_width + tz

    });
}

public void putNormals(FloatBuffer vertexNormalData) {
    float[] normals = new float[] {
            0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    };
```

This is what it looks like when I run the program,
[image: Weird shadows with normals]

It appears that the light is calculated as if each block surrounding it isnt there.  How can I correct this?  The result should look seamless when blocks are flat like in the picture.

Comment: How are you setting up your lights? Are you using the fixed function lights or shaders?

Comment: I am currently using fixed function lights. I set them up in my init function for opengl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 24 positions, but only 6 normal vectors, in your vertex data. You need a normal vector for each vertex. So with 24 positions, you also need 24 normal vectors.

Since the 4 vertices per side have the same normal vector, you need to repeat each of the normal vectors in your `normals` array 4 times, which will give you the necessary 24 normal vectors.

```
vertexNormalData.put(new float[] {
        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
});
```

Comment: I have tried what you said but I still get similar results. It does look marginally better. I don't get the seamless effect I'm looking for though.

Comment: I added the normal definitions to the answer, just to make sure that what I explained was clear.

Comment: Brilliant!  Works like a charm.  I was just putting the vertexNormalData.put into a loop, whoops.